# I'm looking for combine plugin

Tags: merge, notepad++

I set up Notepad++ and searched for combine plugin  but i didn't find it, should i set up another version of Notepad++ and what version may contain  the combine plugin please

[image: combine plugin]

Answer (score 1):

I know this has nothing to do with Notepad++, but consider a different way to achieve the same result.

1. Open your command prompt.
2. Navigate to the folder that contains your files. [Multiple ways to do just that](https://superuser.com/questions/1106976/the-fastest-way-to-open-cmd-in-current-folder-by-shortcut-windows-8-10)
3. Use the `type` command:

```
C:\> type 1.txt 2.txt > 3.txt
```

This command will *combine* the contents of `1.txt` and `2.txt` into `3.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that Combine does not work with the 64-bit version of NotePad++. That is the reason it is not listed in the Plugin Manager.

Install the 32-bit version and it will be there.

Comment: Not there.. I think the plugin is gone